# Why doesn't my discord bot get online when I type node main.js?

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

so I first installed node.js then typed npm init to command prompt then installed discord.js(When installed discord.js it didnt add a node_modules folder inside the project and I think thats where the problem originates from). But when I try to get my bot online(with node main.js command) I see this error message:
Error:

```
Cannot find module 'discord.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Cookie\Desktop\bot\main.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cookie\Desktop\bot\main.js:1:17)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [ ←[32m'C:\\Users\\Cookie\\Desktop\\bot\\main.js'←[39m ]
}
```

here is my package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Cookie482",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "*"
  }
```

and main.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online');
});

client.login('bot-token');
```

Comment: There should be a version as the key for discord js in your depencancies, try reinstalling

Comment: How did that dependency appear in the package.json? That's not how a dependency typically looks after you do `npm install packagename`. Did you type it by hand? Remove that line and execute `npm install discord.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As derpirscher said, remove the line `"discord.js": "*"` from `package.json` and run `npm install discord.js`.

Your `main.js` code is outdated. From v13 onwards you need to specify intents. Replace `const client = new Discord.Client();` with

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
});
```

or some other intents as specified in the documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents)